# creating a primitive type with a class constructor in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, types, constructor

Is there any possibility to define or extend a class for a primitive type like string, number or array? For example i would like to define a Name-class which I can construct with new Name() and just returns the primitive string ""

```
class Name extends String {}

const name = new Name()

name === "" //this is false because String-constructor does not return a primitive string
```

Background:
I have a dictionary of key-value pairs, where the values are either custom classes or primitives (String, Number). I want to be able to construct an object from the class by accessing the class from the dict by the specific key:

```
const dict = {
  "point": Point,
  "area": Area,
  "string": String,
  "name": Name,
  "number": Number,
}

const string = new dict["string"]()
string === "" //false
```

Comment: would it be helpful if you used something like `string.valueOf() === "" // true`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf
and just used the `valueOf()` since that function exists on any Object?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any possibility to define or extend a class for a primitive type like string or number?

**No**.

> or array?

An `Array` is not a primitive value but an object. Yes, you can subclass `Array`, but it is not recommended.

> I have a dictionary of key-value pairs, where the values are either custom classes or primitives (String, Number). I want to be able to construct an object from the class by accessing the class from the dict by the specific key.

Drop the `new`. Store factory functions that return the instance (or primitive value) when you call them without `new`:

```
const dict = {
  "point": () => new Point(),
  "area"() { return new Area(); },
  "string": String,
  "name": () => { return new Name() },
  "number"() { return 0; /* Number() */ },
  // etc
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what  you are after?

The following just returns a new instance of the various objects from the object properties. Where new types are needed, functions define constructors for them.

```js
function Point(){ this.x=0; this.y=0; }
function Area(){ this.r = 3.14; this.c = 42;}
function Name(){}

const dict = {
  point: new Point(),
  area: new Area(),
  string: new String(),
  name: new Name(),
  number: new Number(),
}

console.log(dict.point.x);
console.log(dict.area.r);
```