# Bulma CSS, clear button in input search text field

Tags: javascript, css, bulma

I have a search text field like this one:

```
    <div class="field">
      <p class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
        <input class="input is-normal is-rounded" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
        <span class="icon is-small is-left">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-filter"></i>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
```

I want to add a clear button on it, that clears the text in the field if something is written on it. It would be nice if it appears only if there is some text in the field.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: for the sake of styling the filter button depending on the text being filled or not, you may use [:placeholder-shown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown) as `input:placeholder-shown + span.icon {display: none;}`

Comment: What have you tried? We are not a coding service. We expect that you will do your research and make an attempt before posting here. Then, when you do post, we expect that you will post what you've tried along with a ***specific*** question about the problem you are having.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I read some bulma css documentation and do some search on google: there is the classic button example on the right but it's not what I want. I am asking because I don't know how to get started and I know this is not a coding service, I am not a new member. Feel free  to link me some examples and documentation about this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the CSS pseudo-class `:placeholder-shown` to style the elements you want to hide based on the input condition.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown

So here in this demo I added some css rules that will hide the buttons when the placeholder is still being shown (so when the input is still not filled with text).

Here in this demo I put some efforts to style it the best way possible but there are few caveats. The main problem was using a `span` to model what should be actually a `button` instead for accessibility concerns!

But I wanted to follow the guidelines shown on https://bulma.io/documentation/form/general/ that use that layout for ***icons*** instead. I tried with buttons but they looked very ugly. So please take this detail into account and spend yourself to address that issue.

Look here for further information about that topic: [https://www.boia.org/blog/accessibility-tips-using-the-div-and-span-elements#:~:text=In%20general%2C%20you%20should%20avoid,with%20the%20HTML%20tabindex%20attribute](https://www.boia.org/blog/accessibility-tips-using-the-div-and-span-elements#:%7E:text=In%20general%2C%20you%20should%20avoid,with%20the%20HTML%20tabindex%20attribute).

***side note: I understand that SO is not an helpdesk but yet sometimes I decide it's worth spending time to see if I can solve something for my own purpose and it would be wasted if not shared***

```js
//when page was loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
  
  //add a click event handler to the #clearButton,
  document.getElementById('clearButton')
    .addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      //that will clear the value of the #search text input
      document.getElementById('search').value = '';
    });
    
  //add a click event handler to the #filterButton
  document.getElementById('filterButton')
    .addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      //that will just log something on console
      console.log('filter occurred!');
    });
    
});
```

```css
.field{
  margin: 2em;
}

#search:placeholder-shown + #filterButton {
  display: none;
}

#search:placeholder-shown ~ #clearButton {
  display: none;
}

#clearButton,
#filterButton
{
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="field">
  <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
    <input id="search" class="input is-normal is-rounded" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
    <span id="filterButton" class="icon is-small is-right">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-filter"></i>
    </span>    
    <span id="clearButton" class="icon is-small is-left">
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </span>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't provide answers to poor questions that don't belong here in the first place (like this one) as it just attracts more poor questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the bulma css class `is-hidden` to the icon, then `onInput` of the input element, remove that class to make it visible. Or, if the user removes all the input, `add` the class back to hide it again.

```js
const inputElement = document.querySelector('input');
const inputIcon = document.querySelector('i');

inputElement.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    if (e.target.value.length > 0) {
        inputIcon.classList.remove('is-hidden');
    } else {
        inputIcon.classList.add('is-hidden');
    }
});
```

```css
html, body { height: 100vh; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css">

 <div class="field">
  <p class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
    <input class="input is-normal is-rounded" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-filter is-hidden">:D</i>
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't provide answers to poor questions that don't belong here in the first place (like this one) as it just attracts more poor questions.

Comment: Lol, thanks for your feedback, kinda ironic looking at your last few answers.

Comment: Not really sure what that's supposed to mean. What question did I recently answer that was a poor question that didn't belong on SO in the first place?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought.

Comment: Well if you insist, [the last one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77887635/getting-textcontent-from-multiple-elements-individually-using-one-class-name/77887792#77887792) shows no sign of using the thing he wants. [The answer before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77887204/creating-a-primitive-type-with-a-class-constructor-in-javascript/77887325#77887325) gets a downvote, on a -2 question thats gonna be closed soon, again bad question. [The third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77816038/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-mano/77816193#77816193) ...

Comment: ... seems like an easy duplicate. [Answer before that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77753531/tracking-user-time/77754120#77754120) is already closed, don't need to elaborate that one.